# SQL to Linq converting using where in contains

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have written this SQL statement:

```
select id,ProductAbbr 
from Product  
where id in (Select max(id) from Product group by ProductAbbr)
```

My linq query is :

```
 var prod = (from t in _context.Product
             group t by t.ProductAbbr
             into g
             select new
                    {
                        Id = (from t2 in g select t2.Id).Max()
                    }).ToList();

// int idlist = Int32.Parse(prod);
var request = (from p in _context.Product
               where(p => prod.Contains(p.Id))
               select new
                      {
                          p.Id, p.ProductAbbr
                      }).ToList().Distinct();
```

I get this error

> CS0136 C# A local or parameter named 'p' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just

```
var prod = (from t in _context.Product
            group t by t.ProductAbbr
                       into g
            select new
            {
                Id = (from t2 in g select t2.Id).Max()
            }).ToList();
//int idlist = Int32.Parse(prod);
var request = (from p in _context.Product
               join p1 in prod on p1.Id equals p.Id
               select new
               {
                   p.Id,
                   p.ProductAbbr
               }).ToList().Distinct();
```

?

Note that I have changed

> where(p=> prod.Contains(p.Id))

To

> join p1 in prod on p1.Id equals p.Id

Note that this will make your query syntaxically valid, but it seems to also be possible to rework it in many other ways according to what I see.
The second query doesn't seem to bring anything useful, at least in your example.